# Using custom dispatcher for all user actors in Akka to avoid thread starvation for system actors

Tags: scala, akka

Question is about dispatcher configuration in Akka 2.5.x.

I would like to avoid thread starvation issue that may cause nodes to be quarantines because system messages are not delivered. In order to achieve that I would like to create separate dispatcher which is exactly the same as default dispatcher configuration.

I have defined custom dispatcher configuration with the name `my-dispatcher {...}`. Can I use the following to make Akka use this dispatcher for all user's actors?

```
akka.actor.deployment {
    "/**" { # <- should this work?
        dispatcher = my-dispatcher
...
}
```

Idea came from the following example in documentation:

```
# all direct children of '/user/actorC' have a dedicated dispatcher 
"/actorC/*" {
    dispatcher = my-dispatcher
}
```

So if I replace `actorC` with `**` it will target all actors under `/user`, I would expect it to work. Does anyone do it this way? Or I need to find another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I checked your approach is working and it overrides dispatcher in all actors under *user* path.

Although more conventional approach to configure the default dispatcher would by just overriding entries in config under `akka.actor.default-dispatcher` (you can override only some of them), for example:

```
akka {
  actor {
    default-dispatcher {
      fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-min = 2
      }
      throughput = 100
  }
}
```

If you insinst to use your dispatcher defined with different path in config as default, you could just override `default-dispatcher` section with `my-dispatcher`:

```
akka.actor.default-dispatcher = ${path.to.my-dispatcher}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Re more conventional approach though, would not it override dispatcher for system actors as well? I'd like to have separate dispatchers for them

Comment: I've got an error in my code snippet, but it's fixed now:) I would guess, that setting *default-dispatcher* would work also for system actors, but I would need to confirm it when I'm back home.

Comment: Anyway, your first part of the answer is what I wanted to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: Does change the default dispatcher will not affect the Akka internals? Is it not best practice to create a separate dispatcher for user-defined actors?